# How to regex filter with boolean Mongoose Paginate V2?

Tags: node.js

I use Mongoose Paginate V2 in nodeJs, but i have a question that how to make a regex filter with Boolean type?

My Code is

```
exports.allData = (req, res, next) => {
  const { page, size, title, show } = req.query;
  var condition = {}

  if(title){
    condition.title = { $regex: new RegExp(title), $options: "i" }
  }
  if(tayang){
    condition.show = { $regex: new RegExp(show), $options: "true|false" }
  }

  const { limit, offset } = getPagination(page, size);

  var options = {
    populate: [
    {
      path: 'user',
      select: 'username'
    }],
    sort: ({ createdAt: -1 })
  };

  Article.paginate(condition, { offset, limit, options })
    .then((data) => {
      res.send({
        totalItems: data.totalDocs,
        articles: data.docs,
        totalPages: data.totalPages,
        currentPage: data.page - 1,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      logger.error(req.method + ": " + req.originalUrl + ", message: " + err.message)
      next(createError.InternalServerError())
    });
};
```

I want to filter data "show" field is true or false with regex. Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `show` query param is present and use the [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq) operator to construct the query.

```
if ('show' in req.query) {
  condition.show = { $eq: show === 'true' }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to use it with mongoose paginate?

Comment: But how can i detect the input from params that is true or false.

Comment: @ASHafizullah Not sure what you mean. Can you explain?

Comment: for example, route url is api/article/?show=true then only show the article which show field is true.

Comment: @ASHafizullah Ah, I was under the impression the `show` field was missing in some documents and you wanted to get the documents where it had a boolean value. What should the default value of `show` be if the `show` query param is missing.

Comment: Yes, that i mean

Comment: Thanks, i write ```if(show){ condition.show = { $eq: show }}```

Comment: If the query params has `show=true`, your query will look like `{ show: { $eq: 'true' } }` which will return nothing since it is looking for a string instead of a boolean.